# Extended Choice Parameter plugin Multi-Level Select

Tags: jenkins, plugins, parameters, multi-level

OK, so I downloaded this plugin:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin

And select `Multi-Level Single Select` as the type of parameters.

The problem is that when I have multiple parameters selected and I want to use these parameters in shell in a build, I can only select the LAST parameter

So if I do `$PARAM_NAME` it only outputs the last parameters, but I want all the parameters that I selected, not just the last one.

Here is a picture for demonstration
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You aren't building the parameter based on the selections, you are navigating to the value that you want. I.E. Country --->State ---->City

You aren't building a CountryStateCity variable, you are stating that the City variable is the value you select.

Answer (score 1):

I could get the nearest to this by using **Extended Choice Parameter** > **JSON Parameter Type** > **JSON Parameter Config Groovy Script**.

```
import org.boon.Boon;
def jsonEditorOptions = Boon.fromJson(/{
  disable_edit_json: true,
  disable_properties: true,
  no_additional_properties: true,
  disable_collapse: true,
  disable_array_add: false,
  disable_array_delete: false,
  disable_array_reorder: false,
  theme: "bootstrap3",
  iconlib: "fontawesome5",
  schema: {
   "type": "object",
   "title": "",
   "required": [
    "Locations"
   ],
   "properties": {
    "Locations": {
     "type": "array",
     "format": "table",
     "title": "",
     "uniqueItems": true,
     "items": {
      "type": "object",
      "title": "Location",
      "properties": {
       "Country": {
        "type": "string",
        "propertyOrder" : 1,
        "enum": [
         "USA",
         "Germany",
         "India"
        ]
       },
       "City": {
        "type": "string",
        "propertyOrder" : 2,
        "enum": [
         "New York",
         "Frankfurt",
         "Mumbai"
        ]
       },
       "Neighborhood": {
        "type": "string",
        "propertyOrder" : 3
       }
      }
     },
     "default": [{
      "Country": "USA",
      "City": "New York",
      "Neighborhood": "Times Square"
     }]
    }
   }
  }
  /);
```

> You can visit the [plugin page](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin) and [json-editor.github.io](https://json-editor.github.io/json-editor/) to create and validate your
>   JSON schemas as seen above.

This is how it appears in Jenkins:

[image]

> Note that however, it still does not provide a context sensitive
>   second column based on what is selected in the first column. The
>   second column rather behaves exactly like the first column where you
>   select from a pre-defined list without any filters.

On printing the variable `Location`, it returns this JSON:

```
{"Locations":[{"City":"New York","Country":"USA","Neighborhood":"Times Square"},{"City":"Frankfurt","Country":"Germany","Neighborhood":"Bornheim"},{"City":"Mumbai","Country":"India","Neighborhood":"Vile Parle"}]}
```

Comment: Thanks Dibakar
This helped me in my use case

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem, so I added a 'row number' column to the parameters file:

```
    Country         City            Row
    United States   San Francisco   1
    United States   Chicago         2
    Mexico          Mexico City     3
    Mexico          Cancun          4
```

This way, the plugin returns the row number and I can address that row from the parameters file.