# jenkins extended choice parameter plugin multi select values from a property file

Tags: jenkins-plugins

How do you define the property file to use those values to populate the multi select parameter type of [Extended Choice Parameter](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin) plugin in Jenkins ?

The plugin is in Jenkins version : 0.34.

I tried to configure a multi select based on a property file, but I can't get the plugin to read my property file correctly.

The file is found.

If I put one line in the file, I get an error from the plugin saying it needs two lines at least.

I tried the example with the countries (provided by the help button of the plugin) but it did not work.

Country City
United States   San Francisco
United States   Chicago
Mexico  Mexico City
Mexico  Cancun

I tried with a property file :

a    b
c    d

It didn't work either.

What did I miss?

Can it be an encoding problem ?

I used vi to create the file, is the tabulation ok?

I couldn't find an answer in these threads :

[Populate 'Multi Select' parameter ('Extended Choice Parameter' plugin) in Jenkins dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21289870/populate-multi-select-parameter-extended-choice-parameter-plugin-in-jenkin)

[Extended Choice Parameter plugin Multi-Level Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21003160/extended-choice-parameter-plugin-multi-level-select)

Answer (score 9):

For **multi-level** select lists, you have to enter the *column headers* (Country,City) in the **Value** field.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The Country and Cty mentioned above must be 'Tab space' separated.eg:

```
Country City
United States   San Francisco
United States   Chicago
Mexico  Mexico City
Mexico  Cancun
```